# Creating new field with logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-file

I have a file named "Job Code.txt"

```
job_id=0001,description=Ship data from server to elknode1,result=OK
job_id=0002,description=Ship data from server to elknode2,result=Error: Msg...
job_id=0003,description=Ship data from server to elknode3,result=OK
job_id=0004,description=Ship data from server to elknode4,result=OK
```

Here is the filter part of my .conf file but it doesn't work.  How can I created new field, i.e. jobID, description, result as to be seen in kibana

```
filter{
grok{   match => {"message" => ["JobID: %{NOTSPACE:job_id}","description: %{NOTSPACE:description}","result: %{NOTSPACE:message}"]}
add_field => {
"JobID" => "%{job_id}"
"Description" => "%{description}"
"Message" => "%{message}"
}
}
if [job_id] == "0001" {
aggregate {
task_id => "%{job_id}"
code => "map['time_elasped']=0"
map_action => "create"
}
}
if [job_id] == "0003" {
aggregate {
task_id => "%{job_id}"
code => "map['time_elasped']=0"
map_action => "update"
}
}
if [job_id] == "0002" {
aggregate {
task_id => "%{job_id}"
code => "map['time_elasped']=0"
map_action => "update"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple days old, perhaps you still require an answer. Change your grok statement to:

```
grok {
      match => { "message" => "job_id=%{DATA:job_id},description=%{DATA:description},result=%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
}
```

You won't need the add_field option, grok will create them for you. The add_field option is to add arbitrary fields. Check the pattern at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com

Also, unless there are other messages you want to match, I don't think the aggregate statements you have will do what you want.